# How to provide a REST interface to a SOAP web service?

Tags: rest, soap

I know very little about web programming but I need to establish a license generation web service to provide licenses to users of my desktop software.

I have managed to create a working & debugged SOAP service on a Win2003 server but now I have discovered that the interface that I need to provide to my payment processor must be REST.

How would you recommend I deal with this, given that I simply don't have the time to learn PHP and rewrite my web service etc. I could bypass the SOAP altogether and easily create an executable which receives the license parameters and returns an encrypted license, but it's the web interface bit that I am stuck on. I will probably subcontract someone to write a utility for this on elance, but I don't know what to ask for.

Manu thanks,
Michael

Comment: What language/platform is your service currently built on?

Comment: I've used Windev, an IDE of French origin. It can create a SOAP server but not REST. Is there a simple script engine of some sort that can listen for and read a REST input, run an exe, and pass a result back to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose the same service as SOAP based as well as RESTful. Axis2 with WSDL 2.0 has support for this.

Please see this article [RESTful Web Services with Apache Axis2](http://wso2.org/library/3726) - explains things in detail..

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy conversion from SOAP to REST. SOAP WebServices RESTful APIs use different approaches. I think it is very easy to do with Ruby on Rails (which will take care of 90% of RESTful APi for you). All you need is to implement your logic.

Sinatra example:

```
get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if rather than install the large & complex RoR, there is a simple lightweight tool I can use? I only need it for this single purpose. I don't need a whole framework.

Comment: There's a lightweight Web framework for Ruby called Sinatra (http://www.sinatrarb.com/). Updated my answer

Comment: Could Sinatra execute an exe file?

Comment: Sinatra is Ruby based Web framework. Ruby can execute executables. So yes.

Comment: I've played with RoR before and I like Ruby. However, as this is running on a Win Server 2003, I wonder if ASP could do the trick, and thus avoid having to install another tool.

Comment: I think WCF had REStful bindings you could use. There are several topics here on SO about it.